# How do I wrap a piped stream to make it look like a single stream?

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, gulp

I have a work flow, something like this:

```
gulp.src('**/*.js')
   .pipe(doSomething())
   .pipe(dest('out'));
```

I want `doSomething` to return a stream pipeline, say something like `uglify().pipe(header(...)).pipe(rename(...))` so that the effective result of this is

```
gulp.src('**/*.js')
   .pipe(uglify())
   .pipe(header(...))
   .pipe(rename(...))
   .pipe(dest('out'));
```

Obviously `doSomething` can't return uglify (because dest would read from that), and it can't return rename (because src would write to that).  So my plan was to build a Duplex stream that acted like a wrapper around this pipeline fragment, resulting in this:

```
first = uglify();
last = first
    .pipe(header(...))
    .pipe(rename(...));

gulp.src('**/*.js')
   .pipe(wrapper(first, last) /* writes go to first, reads go to last */)
   .pipe(dest('out'));
```

I've taken a stab at writing a wrapper, but I don't have enough Node Stream experience to know that I'm going down the right path at all, and why it's not working.  Here's what I've got so far:

```
var encapsulateStream = function(first, last, logger) {
  logger('encapsulate');
  let resultStream = new Duplex({
      readableObjectMode: true,
      writableObjectMode: true,
      read(size) {
        logger('read');
        while (true) {
          let chunk = last.read(size);
          if (logger) logger('[in]', '--->', chunk);
          if (!this.push(chunk) || chunk === null) {
            return;
          }
        }
      },
      write(chunk, enc, next) {
        logger('write');
        if (logger) logger('--->', '[first]', chunk);
        first.write(chunk, enc, next);
      }});

  resultStream.on('finish', function() {
    logger('finish');
    first.end();
    forwardStream(last, resultStream, logger);
  });

  return resultStream;
};
```

I get "encapsulate" in my logs, but nothing else.  Where am I going wrong, and is this the right approach?

Comment: There's already a lib for what you're trying to do -> [`lazypipe`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lazypipe)

Comment: Make that comment an answer so I can check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to implement something like this yourself. The [`lazypipe`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lazypipe) library is widely used and does pretty much exactly what you want.

Here's a quick example that illustrates its usage for your use case:

```
var lazypipe = require('lazypipe');

var doSomething = lazypipe()
  .pipe(uglify)
  .pipe(header, ...)
  .pipe(rename, ...);

gulp.src('**/*.js')
  .pipe(doSomething())
  .pipe(gulp.dest('out'));
```